# cannot set property on socket.io handshake object

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I am trying to add a custom attribute to a socket.io handshake and pass it to the socket object at each connection.

Below a very minimal set up of what I am doing:

```
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);

var io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.set('authorization', function(data, callback){
  data.foo = 'bar';
  callback(null, true);
});
```

The above should give access to a foo property on the socket.handshake object, however, doing the following:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.handshake.foo); //This should return bar
});
```

Returns an undefined.

Comment: I think the object you are defining foo on is a copy instead of a reference to the actual handsake object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Socket.IO 1.0, there is no more `handshake` object, it's been replaced by `socket.request`.

That should work :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.request.foo);
});
```

[Look here for more info on the differences between 0.9 and 1.0.](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/)

Keep in mind that most of the resources/tutorials you'll find online will be using Socket.IO 0.9, so the knowledge on this page is very useful ;)